# Proxy authentication issue using Jsoupbrowser in container

Tags: scala, docker, authentication, proxy, jsoup

I'm having an issue trying to authenticate my proxy inside a Docker.

That's what I did :

```
 Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
      override def getPasswordAuthentication = new PasswordAuthentication(<USERNAME>, <PASSWORD>.toCharArray)
    })

    val browser = new JsoupBrowser(ua,proxy) {
      override def requestSettings(conn: Connection) = conn.timeout(5000)
    }

    // Step 1: We __scrape__ the current page.
    val doc = browser.get(baseUrl)
```

It works locally, but when I deploy it on my server I get an Error 407

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"
```

I also tried upgrading the configuration to container level but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
The problem was only at the deploy, so I concluded that the problem came with the build of the docker.

I add this JVM parameter in my Dockerfile :

```
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=
```

To the CMD

```
CMD java -Dhttp.port=${port} -Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes= -Dplay.crypto.secret=secret $* -jar ./app-assembly.jar
```

It works now.